# How to make camera custom in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, camera, cross-platform

i am gonna building a flutter app which focuses on the camera , like snapshat , filters , masks , effects , and write text on the camera while filming and so ,, Is this possible in Flutter ?

I have no idea where to start

Comment: Check camera package. It allows modifying UI.

Comment: i tried this , but didnt find masks into it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.